# Filling a circle with a centered angular gradient does not properly center

Tags: swift, gradient, swiftui

I was watching the WDDC session 237 video and saw an interesting example of creating a "color wheel"-esque circle using gradients and shapes with SwiftUI, so I tried to duplicate it in my code, but I didn't get the same result.

This is the code:

```
let spectrum = Gradient(colors: [.red, .yellow, .green, .blue, .purple, .red])
let conic = AngularGradient(gradient: spectrum, center: .center, angle: Angle(degrees: -90))
return Circle().fill(conic)
```

But it centers near the bottom instead of the center of the circle. On the other hand, doing the example same thing on an `Ellipse` and `Capsule` works as expected:

Ellipse:

```
let spectrum = Gradient(colors: [.red, .yellow, .green, .blue, .purple, .red])
let conic = AngularGradient(gradient: spectrum, center: .center, angle: Angle(degrees: -90))
return Ellipse().fill(conic)
```

Capsule:

```
let spectrum = Gradient(colors: [.red, .yellow, .green, .blue, .purple, .red])
let conic = AngularGradient(gradient: spectrum, center: .center, angle: Angle(degrees: -90))
return Capsule().fill(conic)
```

Here are images of how the three of them look:

[image: Circle] [image: Ellipse] [image: Capsule]

Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Comment: Updating the frame before the fill gives me the error `Protocol type 'Any' cannot conform to 'View' because only concrete types can conform to protocols`

Comment: OK, thanks for trying though :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Circle` seems to require `.aspectRatio(contentMode: ContentMode.fit)`, for the gradient to work.

```swift
struct ContentView : View {

    var body: some View {
        let spectrum = Gradient(colors: [
            .red, .yellow, .green, .blue, .purple, .red
        ])
        let conic = AngularGradient(gradient: spectrum,
                                    center: .center,
                                    angle: Angle(degrees: -90))
        return VStack {
            Circle().fill(conic).aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
            Ellipse().fill(conic)
            Capsule().fill(conic)
        }
    }

}
```

**Output**:

[image]

Comment: @RPatel99 no idea, unfortunately

Comment: If `.aspectRatio(contentMode: ContentMode.fit)` modifier applied to any of these three shapes, it will draw a circle. :D

Answer (score 0):

Draw ellipse itself with aspect ratio,

like

```swift
return Ellipse()
    .fill(conic)
    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
```

**UPDATE:**

If `.aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)` modifier applied to any of these three shapes, it will draw a circle.

Comment: Did you mean `Circle`? The ellipse's gradient is already centered as expected.

Comment: With ellipse also, you can draw a circle. Please try the code